# How to Archive Message in Ejabberd and store in MongoDB

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ejabberd, xmppframework

I need help on ejabberd message archiving and store all the chat in **MongoDB**.
I tried this https://github.com/kongo2002/ejabberd-mod-mam/ but No Luck.
I install the ejabberd 2.1.10
anyone else facing the same problem??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That module is not made for the very old ejabberd 2.1 (See the yaml configuration file example).

You should try with ejabberd 14.07 or even better 14.12.

Comment: Hi, right now i am moving on win 8 and i install the ejabberd 2.1.11 and MongoDB 2.6.6. I configure the ejabberd config file as on my github here https://github.com/HiteshSongra/eJabberd-Message-Archive- , Please look into this and guide me more. after adding the mod_mam module ejabberd is working fine but there is no data store into the database.

Comment: @Mickaël , what module you would suggest for archiving messages in MySql? I am using Ejabberd 15.04.

Comment: Ejabberd community edition does not yet have a backend for MySQL, but this is coming in June.